# How to change checkbox style in LongListMultiSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to change checkbox style in LongListMultiSelector. How can i do that? [Default checkbox is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61995906/now.PNG), but i [need something like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61995906/Need.PNG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the style of the CheckBox, use Blend to help.
When you are on the style of the checkbox look at the States window in Blend, it will help you modify the VisualStates.

I've made something that look like the thing you want:

```
        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="list" >
            <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style  BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF32DE00"/>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA0A0A0"/>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <Border x:Name="CheckBackground" BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32" BorderBrush="#FF38F102" Background="White"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="21" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="23"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.Resources>
        </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

Feel free to modify the style to match your expectation.